# Rodapé não está sendo responsivo

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, footer

Eu fiz um site e o restante está responsivo, sem problema algum. Mas, o meu footer, está ficando por cima de outros elementos quando vou testar em telas menores.

**HTML:**

```
<footer class="footersection" id="aboutus">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 footer-div">
                      <div>
                    <h3>SOBRE A EMPRESA</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum enim lobortis consectetur quis congue 
                    fames quis suspendisse torquent imperdiet orem ipsum 
                    enim lobortis consectetur quis congue fames quis 
                    suspendisse torquent imperdiet</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-12 footer-div text-center">
                  <div>
                <h3>LINK DE NAVEGAÇÃO</h3>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Serviço</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Preço</a></li>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 footer-div">
              <div>
            <h3>SOBRE A EMPRESA</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum enim lobortis consectetur quis congue 
            fames quis suspendisse torquent imperdiet orem ipsum 
            enim lobortis consectetur quis congue fames quis 
            suspendisse torquent imperdiet</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-5 text-center">
          <p class="text-center"> ©2020 Todos os direitos reservados</p>
        </div>

      </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
.footersection{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding:70px 0 20px;
    background: #00abff;
    position: absolute;
}
.footersection p{
    color:#fff;
}
.footersection li a{
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.footersection h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size: 1.2rem!important;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: É só tirar o position: absolute; do footer

Answer (score -1):

Ele fica por cima por conta do position:absolute, uma coisa que tu pode fazer é declarar um min-height:90vh; no elemento onde fica teu conteúdo, anterior ao footer, aí sempre que tua página não tiver conteúdo suficiente para ocupar a tela teu footer se mantém sempre no fim da página e não sobe lá pro meio dela. O tamanho da altura eu coloquei 90 de exemplo, pode mudar de acordo com a altura do teu footer

Comment: Obrigada! Deu super certo!

Answer (score -2):

Tente retirar o

```
position: absolute
```

Comment: Obrigada! Consegui!